# Excel formula to exclude rows in an array if a duplicate number is present in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that returns an array that looks like this (the asterisks next to the duplicates are not present in the array):

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text | Text | Text | 1 |
| Text | Text | Text | 2 |
| Text | Text | Text | 2 * |
| Text | Text | Text | 3 |
| Text | Text | Text | 4 |
| Text | Text | Text | 4 * |
| Text | Text | Text | 2 * |

The array is of variable length but fixed width.

How could I exclude any row where column D contains a duplicate number? There may be multiple duplicate values, so for the example above I would want to remove all 3 marked rows.

Comment: Can you show the formula, which produces this array?

Comment: Do a count - if greater than 1 ignore.

Comment: You need to specify how to choose a row to keep. Or are they completely identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Retrieve Rows By Unique Column

**Result (in `F2`)**

MS366

```
=LET(data,A2#,ucol,4,
    u,CHOOSECOLS(data,ucol),
CHOOSEROWS(data,XMATCH(UNIQUE(u),u)))
```

Excel 2021

```
=LET(data,A2#,ucol,4,
    u,INDEX(data,,ucol),
INDEX(data,XMATCH(UNIQUE(u),u),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data))))
```

[image]

**Sample Data (in `A2`)**

MS365

```
=HSTACK(SEQUENCE(10,3),RANDARRAY(10,,1,5,1))
```

Excel 2021

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(,4)<4,SEQUENCE(10,3),RANDARRAY(10,,1,5,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=UNIQUE(CHOOSEROWS(<R>,XMATCH(DROP(<R>,,3),DROP(<R>,,3))))
```

**Caution:**

- `<R>` - merely a placeholder for your array;
- This would return rows top-down, irrespective of the data in the 1st-3rd column.